# Identifying conference and journal papers

Tags: publications

how do I know whether a paper is a conference or a journal paper from its citation.

Comment: Why do you care?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the citation will give the name of the journal or the name of the event. Usually it is clear from this whether it *is* a journal or an event.

Comment: ...and if it isn't, a quick search usually clears it up.

Comment: Many conference proceedings are published as a special issue in a journal. Without seeing the journal issue more broadly you can not easily tell.